Given two positive integers $a,b$ suppose $|a-b| = n$, does there always exist $c = \Theta(\sqrt{n})$ such that $a\bmod c$ and $b\bmod c$ are close?
This might be a classic number theory result but I couldn't find it.
As the title says, given two positive integers $a,b$ suppose $|a-b| = n$, does there always exist $c = \Theta(\sqrt{n})$ such that $a \bmod c$ and $b \bmod c$ are close?
i.e. $$i = a \bmod c$$
$$j = b\bmod c$$
$$|i-j| = O(\log n)$$
If this is true, is $|i-j| = O(\log n)$ tight for $c = \Theta(\sqrt{n})$? How do we prove it?
If this is not true, is $|i-j| = O(n^{0.5 - \varepsilon})$? If not, how do we find an infinite family of hard pair of integers?
Note: $|i-j|$ can either be wrapping around or not wrapping around i.e. 999 and 2001 are close $mod$ 1000 if wrapping around. We are interested in both cases.
Note2: For wrapping around case, we can make $a = 0$, so $i = 0$, proving for this case is equivalent.
Note3: The large $c = \Theta(\sqrt{n})$ will map $n$ elements(numbers) into exactly $\Theta(\sqrt{n})$ ordered ''bins". We can define some metric of these ''bins". A good answer to this question can be applied to reducing any problem that holds some property through such kind of mapping. A guaranteed small $|i - j|$ gap will improve some lower polynomial algorithms.
In general, the distribution of the residues around $\Theta(\sqrt{n})$ appears to be uniformly random, then there should be a certain size of ball that is never empty. I think that this has many implications in combinatorics.

Not sure I follow. Why not just take $c=2$?  Then $|i-j|$ is at most $1$.  Or, if some prime $p<n$ divides $p$ take $c=p$, so $i=j$.  If $n$ happens to be a prime, take a prime dividing $n+1$, in which case $i,j$ differ by $1$.  Or did you mean something else?

Oh, my bad, I will fix it real quick. I think the point is $c$ cannot be too small.

Ok, so (post edit) you need one of the numbers "near" $n$ to be divisible by a number near $\sqrt n$.  Seems reasonable.   After all you can take the product of the floor and ceiling of $\sqrt n$.

@MishaLavrov Ah, it does not wrap around. So 999 and 2001 are not close around 1000. But I am also curious about the wrap around case.

@lulu Maybe we can just find the smallest "near-prime" number bigger than $n$ that has two factors and say it has a factor of $O(\sqrt{n})$?

I suggest:  try my algorithm.  It hands you a value for $c$, obviously near $\sqrt n$.  See if it passes your test or how badly it fails if it fails.

@lulu Yes practically I would try that. But the question is asking for the proof of existence of such a good $c$.

Ok, so you have to try things.  Might not get it right the first time.  If my algorithm works, you are done. If it fails, then maybe you get some insight as to how to repair it, or you get evidence that helps you produce a bad family of values of $n$.

@lulu We can program and verify if your algorithm works for some $n$, but it is not done yet. I believe it works for all $|a-b| = n$.

You can also write it out analytically.  Writing $c=\lfloor \sqrt n\rfloor$ we have $c=\sqrt n - x$ for some $x\in (0,1)$ (I am assuming that $n$ is not a square, as that case is easy).  Thus you want to write out how much  $(\sqrt n -x )(\sqrt n -x+1)$ differs from $n$ and see if it is close enough.

@lulu $(\sqrt{n} - x)(\sqrt{n} -x +1) -n= (1-2x)\sqrt{n}$ if $x$ is some constant 0,1, then this brings down to $(\sqrt{n} - x)(\sqrt{n} -x +1) -n = O(\sqrt{n})$ but we want to see if we can make $O(\log n)$ if we extend the range of $c$.

Ok, so see if you can improve on my algorithm.  In cases where the distance is nearly $\sqrt n$, can you find much better choices for $c$?  I figure that any algorithm is going to have to look something like this...you can't count on factoring all the numbers near $n$.  Factoring is too hard.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I really don't have any better ideas.  Like I say, I'd look at examples where you can find much better choices for $c$...see if there is any pattern to those or if it always looks arbitrary.  Are you certain that it is possible?  If not, maybe you can use bad cases for the algorithm to prove that it can't be done. Won't be easy...as the estimates have unspecified constants in them, you'll need an infinite family of bad examples to rule it out.

I think we can always make $a=0$, so that we can just focus on $n$.

We can only assume $a=0$ if we wrap around. Otherwise, say $a=9999$ and $b=20001$; then $c=100$ does not work ($99$ and $1$ are not close) but if we replace $a,b$ by $0$ and $b-a = 10002$, then $c=100$ does work ($0$ and $2$ are close).

@MishaLavrov That makes sense. Added some notes to the problem.

What is the motivation for this question?  Why is it relevant to others?  Is there an application, or did you encounter it somewhere?

@D.W. This one popped up several times during the past several years. I can remember that it first emerged because I wanted to test the distribution of the residue. Then I think around 9 years ago, I tried to apply this to some fine-grained low-polynomial complexity problems. We figured that even getting this down to $O(n^{\frac{1}{2} - \varepsilon})$ can get us to some sub-quadratic/cubic time results. Now I am working on some small ball probability problem it haunted me again. Some problem that has similar vibe is here: http://www.openproblemgarden.org/comment/reply/819

Thanks very much for the explanation.  I suggest editing the question to add a paragraph at the end that describes the motivation.  I think that might help make it interesting and relevant to others, and we don't want to have information buried in the comments -- instead, comments are designed to help you revise your question to improve it.

@D.W. Thanks, I added some paragraphs. I thought this should be studied somewhere so I was expecting some quick answer. It turns out that it might not be easy.

Here's a proof that you can achieve $|i - j| < O(n^{0.25})$.
Let $c := \lceil n^{0.5} \rceil$, let $d := \lfloor \frac n c \rfloor$, and let $r := n \bmod c$.
Let $k = \lfloor (c - r)^{0.5} \rfloor$. Then
\begin{align}
n - ((c + k)(d - k)) &= r + k^2 \\
&= c \\
&= (c + k) - k
\end{align}
So we see that choosing $c_1 := c + k$ gives us that $|a - b| \bmod c_1 = c_1 - O(n^{0.25})$. We may have that $a$ and $b$ fall on opposite sides of $c_1$, but if this is the case we can just increment $k$ by 1 or 2.

Nice trick! Can we improve further?
